# Import Error in __init__.py : No Module named _vlfeat in PyVlfeat

Tags: python, vlfeat

I am trying to run this python rewrite of Vlfeat library.
https://github.com/shackenberg/phow_caltech101.py. I am trying to run the application phow_caltech101.

This is throwing

```
File "/A/B/C/pyvlfeat-0.1.1a3/vlfeat/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
import _vlfeat
ImportError: No module named _vlfeat
```

In the corresponding "**init**.py" file, I can see it is mentioned as "import _vlfeat". I  am new to python, please let me know what is causing this error?

Answer (score 0):

You need to download and install PyVlfeat module.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyvlfeat/

As I see, pyvlfeat has some dependencies, so be sure to download these too:

Boost.Python (tested against version 1.35.0-5)
NumPy (tested against version 1.5.1)
Matplotlib (tested against version 0.99.3)

Comment: I have compiled and installed PyVlfeat in my system. The error is being thrown from the file in this location- pyvlfeat-0.1.1a3/vlfeat/__init__.py

ie, it is already accessing a file in my pyvlfeat installation directory.

Comment: @Erdnase are you sure you installed it without any errors with all of its dependencies?

Comment: Yes, I installed it correctly without any errors. and I have numpy and matplotlib working correctly in other projects. Is there a way to test my pyvlfeat installation through some helloworld python program?

Comment: Oh.. It was 3 years before . And if my memory is right, I was not able to resolve it. Are you getting a similar error?